# When I run this code, a blank Tkinter window without button appears

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def printName(event):
    name = input("what is your name?")
    print("My name is" + name)


    printButton = Button(root,text = "Cliek Me")
    printButton.bind("<Button-1>",printNme)
    printButton.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html - I'm pretty certain you need a frame and the button attached to that frame.

Comment: Avoid calling console `input` with GUI application because if there is no console open, the application will be blocked and no way to resume except killing it.

Comment: Are you intentionally putting the code that creates the buttoon _inside_ `printName`?

Answer (score 0):

The below code should fix your problem. Fill the blanks within quotes as required by your code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


def printName():
    name = input("what is your name?")
    print("My name is" + "")

    printButton = Button(root, text="Cliek Me")
    printButton.bind("<Button-1>", "")
    printButton.pack()

    root.mainloop()
printName()
```